# How to do a sheet of problems with a big frame

Tags: formatting

I'm trying to do a collection of exercises of heat transfer and I want to put them into a good format of a sheet of problems. I want to put a big frame in each page and inside it the title of the chapter in a box which leads from one margin to the other. Inside the frame I would write the sections and subsections. Any idea?. Thanks for advance.

Comment: I don't suppose you could draw a picture?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\fboxsep2em
\begin{document}\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][.4\textheight][t]{\linewidth}
\fboxrule1pt\fboxsep1em
\hfil \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][4ex][c]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2em}
\chapter{The Chapter}
\end{minipage}}\vspace{1em}
\section{The section}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```